# Error : Key not found in QueryDict

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-2.7, django-views

remove_1 and remove_2 are getting called on two separate URL with ajax POST .

```
def remove_1(request):        
    if not request.is_ajax():
        return              
    if request.POST['remove_1_k']:   
        remove_1_rec = db.Query(user_guide).filter('remove_1_k =', int(request.POST['remove_1_k'])).get()        
        remove_1_rec.delete()         
        return HttpResponse('Remove one is done')

def remove_2(request):        
    if not request.is_ajax():
        return             
    if request.POST['remove_2_k']:   
        remove_2_rec = db.Query(faqs).filter('remove_2_k =', int(request.POST['remove_2_k'])).get()        
        remove_2_rec.delete()         
        return HttpResponse('Remove two is done')
```

But I want to combine this function such a way that I should be able to delete remove_1_rec  if request.POST['remove_1_k'] or able to delete remove_2_rec if request.POST['remove_2_k'].

**But When I put these two in if and elif and passes the ajax POST for "remove_2_k" then following Error is coming** :

MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'remove_1_k' not found in < QueryDict: {u'remove_2_k': [u'1'], u'faq_quest': [u'q1'], u'faq_answer': [u'a1']}>"

How can I solve this ?

Comment: please show your javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `request.POST` is dict like object you can use `.get()` with some added bonuses.

Change your `if` to this

```
if request.POST.get('remove_1_k'):
   #do stuff to 1_k
elif request.POST.get('remove_2_k').
   #do stuff to 2_k
```

This will keep it from raising the `KeyError`.

The `.get()` will return the value from the key or `None` if no default value is supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are getting list of values, so do `request.POST.getlist('remove_1_k')`. It will give you list of values for that key, then use appropriate indexing to get required value.

Like

```
rk1 = request.POST.getlist('remove_1_k')
remove_1_rec = db.Query(user_guide).filter('remove_1_k =', 
                 int(request.POST.getlist('remove_1_k')[0]))
                 .get()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am calling one url from two different functions in js. So I am not passing list, just passing one value at a time. Your answer will also work for me if I will be merging my js code in one function. I will try with this possibility also. Thanks once again